# Linking step doesn't get object files from correct location

Tags: makefile

I've written a makefile that links in a few ffmpeg libraries and compiles a basic hello world piece of code. I want all the object files and the executable to go into a ./bin folder. 
I use vpath to include the ./bin directory when dealing with .o files.
When I compile after a make clean, the very first time, during the link step, it tries to get the .o file from the current directory, instead of the path specified in the vpath. The second time though, there isn't a problem.

I also create the bin directory folder in the make file and this may have something to do with it, however, I don't see a problem in the compile step when it generates the .o files.

Here is the make file:

```
ifeq (0, ${MAKELEVEL})
cur-dir := $(shell pwd)
whoami  := $(shell whoami )
host-type := $(shell arch )
endif

CC=gcc
CFLAGS :=-c -Wall -pthread -o $(BINDIR)/$@
LDFLAGS :=-lpthread
FFMPEG := ${cur-dir}/ffmpeg
FFLIBS := -lavcodec -lavdevice -lavformat
FFLIBPATH := -L${FFMPEG}/libavcodec -L${FFMPEG}/libavdevice -L${FFMPEG}/libavformat
SOURCES := pthreadEx.c
OBJECTS := $(SOURCES:.c=.o)
BINDIR := ./bin
EXECUTABLE := micgrabber
INCFILE := -I${FFMPEG}/libavformat \
           -I${FFMPEG}/libavcodec \
           -I${FFMPEG}/libavdevice

vpath %.o $(BINDIR)
all: directories $(OBJECTS) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(FFLIBPATH) $(FFLIBS) $< -o $(BINDIR)/$@

pthreadEx.o: pthreadEx.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $(BINDIR)/$@

clean:
    rm -rf *.o
    rm -rf $(BINDIR)

.PHONY: directories

directories: ${BINDIR}

${BINDIR}: 
    mkdir -p ${BINDIR}
```

I'm not sure why, on the first attempt to compile, it looks in the wrong place for the .o file.

Here is the output ( including the gcc command generated ) after running make for the first time.

```
[root@KartikCentOSVM sf_audioProj]# make clean
rm -rf *.o
rm -rf ./bin
[root@KartikCentOSVM sf_audioProj]# make
mkdir -p ./bin
gcc -c -Wall -pthread -o / pthreadEx.c -o ./bin/pthreadEx.o
gcc -lpthread -L/media/sf_audioProj/ffmpeg/libavcodec -L/media/sf_audioProj/ffmpeg/libavdevice 
-L/media/sf_audioProj/ffmpeg/libavformat -lavcodec -lavdevice -lavformat 
pthreadEx.o -o ./bin/micgrabber
gcc: pthreadEx.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [micgrabber] Error 1
```

At this point, the bin directory has been created and the compile step succeeded and there is a pthreadEx.o file in the bin folder. However the link step fails. I run make again and this is what I get now.

```
[root@KartikCentOSVM sf_audioProj]# make
gcc -lpthread -L/media/sf_audioProj/ffmpeg/libavcodec -L/media/sf_audioProj/ffmpeg
/libavdevice -L/media/sf_audioProj/ffmpeg/libavformat -lavcodec -lavdevice -lavformat 
./bin/pthreadEx.o -o ./bin/micgrabber
```

The compile step isn't performed because the object file exists and is current, and this time the link step sources the object file from the correct location.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong in my makefile ?

Comment: I have no answer; but whenever I look at it, I find that VPATH never quite does what I want it to.  Nowadays, I just have an explicit $(OBJDIR)/ all over my Makefiles.

Comment: VPATH works great as long as you understand its purpose: it is ONLY to locate _source_ files (that is, files which are not built by make but are expected to already exist).  You should _never_ use it to try to locate target files (files that make generates).  If you follow this rule VPATH won't surprise you.  Of course, that means you can't use it in the way you have done above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know that this is the entire problem, but this rule:

```
pthreadEx.o: pthreadEx.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $(BINDIR)/$@
```

is lying to `make`. It says that the `$(CC)` command takes `pthreadEx.c`, which should be subject to vpath lookup (but that seems to not be necessary in this case) and produces `pthreadEx.o` in the current directory (targets are not automatically assumed to be going into a vpath location). However, the actual command puts `pthreadEx.o` in `$(BINDIR)`.

This rule might be better:

```
$(BINDIR)/pthreadEx.o: pthreadEx.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Honestly, I'm with Adrian in his comment above - dispense with the vpath bit and just make your rules explicit. vpath-ing can cause all sorts of general wonkiness that's hard to debug.